# Android application crashing?

Tags: android, crash, android-activity, restart

I have created an application in which on click of a button say [next] . I'm calling a method the work of this method is to generate 5 random number and set them on to 5 buttons randomly, on click of each of button it will randomly choose a small (2 sec) audio file and play it.
if i'm clicking the button [next] for more than 8 times my whole application is restarting.

logcat is not showing any error...

```
TextView addNo1, addNo2;
Button option1, option2, option3, option4, next;
Random randomGenerator;
Integer randomInt1, randomInt2;
int flag = 0, setans;
MediaPlayer wa1,wa2,wa3,wa4,wa5,wa6,wa7;
MediaPlayerHelper m;
MediaPlayer mp1, mp2, mp3, mp4, mp5, mp6, mp7, mp8, mp9, mp10, mp11, mp12,
        mp13, mp14, mp15, mp16, mp17, mp18, mp19, mp20;
int correctmusiclist[] = { R.raw.correct1, R.raw.correct2, R.raw.correct3,
        R.raw.correct4, R.raw.correct5, R.raw.correct6, R.raw.correct7,
        R.raw.correct8, R.raw.correct9, R.raw.correct10, R.raw.correct11,
        R.raw.correct12, R.raw.correct13, R.raw.correct14, R.raw.correct15 };
int wrongmusiclist[] = {R.raw.wrong1,R.raw.wrong2,R.raw.wrong3,R.raw.wrong4,R.raw.wrong5,R.raw.wrong6,
        R.raw.wrong7}; 
Context context = Addition.this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.additionactivity);
    addNo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    addNo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    option1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addoption1);
    option2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addoption2);
    option3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addoption3);
    option4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addoption4);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextChangeAdd();
        }
    });
    m = new MediaPlayerHelper(Addition.this);
    randomGenerator = new Random();
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/StefanieDots.ttf");
    addNo1.setTypeface(tf);
    nextChangeAdd();

}

public void nextChangeAdd() {
    randomInt1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    setans = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
    if (setans == 0) {
        setans++;
    }
    int ans = randomInt1 + randomInt2;
    String addans = Integer.toString(ans);
    addNo1.setText(randomInt1.toString());
    addNo2.setText(randomInt2.toString());
    List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        while (true) {
            Integer next = randomGenerator.nextInt(19) + 1;
            if (!generated.contains(ans)) {
                generated.add(next);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    switch (setans) {
    case 1:
        flag = 1;
        option1.setText(addans);
        option1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAudio();
            }
        });

        break;
    case 2:
        flag = 2;
        option2.setText(addans);
        option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAudio();
            }
        });

        break;
    case 3:
        flag = 3;
        option3.setText(addans);
        option3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAudio();
            }
        });
        break;
    case 4:
        flag = 4;
        option4.setText(addans);
        option4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAudio();
            }
        });
                    break;
    }
    String a2 = generated.get(0).toString();
    String a3 = generated.get(1).toString();
    String a4 = generated.get(2).toString();

    if (flag == 1) {
        option2.setText(a2);
        option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
        option3.setText(a3);
        option3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
        option4.setText(a4);
        option4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
    }
    if (flag == 2) {
        option1.setText(a2);
        option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
        option3.setText(a3);
        option3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
        option4.setText(a4);
        option4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
    }
    if (flag == 3) {
        option2.setText(a2);
        option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
        option1.setText(a3);
        option1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
        option4.setText(a4);
        option4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
    }

    if (flag == 4) {
        option2.setText(a2);
        option2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
        option3.setText(a3);
        option3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
        option1.setText(a4);
        option1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wrongAns();
            }
        });
    }
}

public void getAudio() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int i = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[0]);
    mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[1]);
    mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[2]);
    mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[3]);
    mp5 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[4]);
    mp6 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[5]);
    mp7 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[6]);
    mp8 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[7]);
    mp9 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[8]);
    mp10 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[9]);
    mp11 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[10]);
    mp12 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[11]);
    mp13 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[12]);
    mp14 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[13]);
    mp15 = MediaPlayer.create(context, correctmusiclist[14]);
    switch (i) {
    case 1:
        mp1.start();
        break;
    case 2:
        mp2.start();
        break;
    case 3:
        mp3.start();
        break;
    case 4:
        mp4.start();
        break;
    case 5:
        mp5.start();
        break;
    case 6:
        mp6.start();
        break;
    case 7:
        mp7.start();
        break;
    case 8:
        mp8.start();
        break;
    case 9:
        mp9.start();
        break;
    case 10:
        mp10.start();
        break;
    case 11:
        mp11.start();
        break;
    case 12:
        mp12.start();
        break;
    case 13:
        mp13.start();
        break;
    case 14:
        mp14.start();
        break;
    case 15:
        mp15.start();
        break;
    default:
        mp10.start();
    }

}

public void wrongAns()
{
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int i = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    wa1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, wrongmusiclist[0]);
    wa2 = MediaPlayer.create(context, wrongmusiclist[1]);
    wa3 = MediaPlayer.create(context, wrongmusiclist[2]);
    wa4 = MediaPlayer.create(context, wrongmusiclist[3]);
    wa5 = MediaPlayer.create(context, wrongmusiclist[4]);
    wa6 = MediaPlayer.create(context, wrongmusiclist[5]);
    wa7 = MediaPlayer.create(context, wrongmusiclist[6]);
    switch (i) {
    case 1:
        wa1.start();
        break;
    case 2:
        wa2.start();
        break;
    case 3:
        wa3.start();
        break;
    case 4:
        wa4.start();
        break;
    case 5:
        wa5.start();
        break;
    case 6:
        wa6.start();
        break;
    case 7:
        wa7.start();
        break;
    default:
        wa7.start();
}
```

}
}

Comment: please share the logcat logs...

Comment: Post your relevant code and LogCat errors, so we can help you.

Comment: Try running `nextChangeAdd()` outside of the `onClick()`, just to verify it works.

Comment: its working my onCreate method is calling...it...

Comment: Thank you for posting the code, but we also need to see the LogCat errors.

Comment: 11-28 18:27:04.758: I/Choreographer(7651): Skipped 2007 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: You're creating an awful lot of MediaPlayers and never releasing them. The app might just be running out of resources. Read through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html), especially the Releasing the MediaPlayer section.

Answer (score 0):

First of all inside the getAudio()  and wrongAns() for playing random audio is totally wrong,As your totally messing with it by creating so many MediaPlayer objects. The thing that you need here to create only one MediaPlayer object upon random number generation and play the sound in switch case. Something like this

```
 Random randomGenerator = new Random();
 int i = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);


switch (i) {
case 1:
    wa1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, wrongmusiclist[1]);
    wa1.start();
    break;
case 2: 
    wa1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, wrongmusiclist[2]);
    wa1.start();
    break;
```

and made wa1 as class level variable.

**update**
 use this function to play audio

```
public void playBeep() {
try {

    if (m.isPlaying()) {
        m.stop();
        m.release();
        m = new MediaPlayer();
    }
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("beepbeep.mp3");
    m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
    descriptor.close();

    m.prepare();
    m.setVolume(1f, 1f);
    m.setLooping(true);
    m.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

and store the file paths in a array of strings. and pass this function the random number and select the random index from array to different file path.

Comment: i have tried this but still facing the same problem..........is there any other way to do this task...?